# RxJS incrementally validate a stream of events

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a `state` object with string keys and values. Events are coming in, containing key-value pairs to change the `state`.

I need a debounced stream that:

- validates the events and drop all modifications in the debounce cycle if they lead to an invalid state
- outputs the diff to the last valid state

For example, for the initial state of `{k1: "v1"}`, and an event of `{k2: "v2"}`, output `{k2: "v2"}`.

But for the events: `{k3: "v3"}` and `{k4: "invalid"}`, drop both changes. So when a new event `{k5: "v5"}` comes in, the `k3` key is still undefined.

I was able to implement it, but only by using a new Subject that keeps track of the last valid state: ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sashee/oo2ad4eq/1/))

```js
const lastValidState = new Rx.Subject();

const res = modifications
  .buffer(debounce)
  .withLatestFrom(lastValidState.startWith(state))
  .map(([mods, last]) => {
    // calculate next state
    return [Object.assign({}, last, ...mods), last];
  }).filter(([newState]) => {
    // check new state
    return Object.keys(newState).every((k) => !newState[k].startsWith("invalid"));
  // update Subject
  }).do(([newState]) => lastValidState.next(newState)).share()
  .map(([newState, last]) => {
    // output diff
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(newState).filter((k) => newState[k] !== last[k]).map((k) => ({[k]: newState[k]})))
  }
)
```

This code works well, but I don't like the new Subject it introduces. I would prefer a solution that does not rely on that and use only RxJS operators.

I've tried to use `pairwise`, but I could not figure out how to pair a stream with the last value of itself.

Comment: You most likely need to use [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan), but without a marble diagram, this question is not easy to interpret.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [cartant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745048/rxjs-incrementally-validate-a-stream-of-events?noredirect=1#comment76471177_44745048), using `scan` is the way to go.

The only trick is to use `distinctUntilChanged` to prevent emits for invalid changes.

The modified code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sashee/0wdt7j4r/)

```
const res = modifications
  .buffer(debounce)
  .scan((last, mods) => {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, last, ...mods);
    const valid = Object.keys(newState).every((k) => !newState[k].startsWith("invalid"));

    if (valid) {
        return Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(newState).filter((k) => newState[k] !== last[k]).map((k) => ({[k]: newState[k]})));
    }else {
        return last;
    }
  }, state)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
```